# Self-indexing (and traditional indexing) algorithms - Implementations and advice to share?

Tags: algorithm, search, data-structures, indexing, information-retrieval

As part of a research project I'm currently looking for open-source implementations of self-indexing algorithms, i.e. a compressed form of the traditional inverted index yielding nice characteristics such as faster lookup and/or less consumed space.

Do you know of any open-source implementations of self-indexing algorithms? Do you have other interesting takes on indexing algorithms or data structures to share?

All languages and license variants are welcome.

Comment: Did you find any implementation that you could use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a nice [introductory presentation on self-indexing](http://www.stringology.org/event/2009/psc09p01_presentation.pdf) (PDF).

Answer (score 2):

Look at this page: http://pizzachili.dcc.uchile.cl/, it offers a lot of the existing implementations for those indexes.

Some background and a description of the page can be found in this paper: http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1455268